# PHP BLOB Field data different than original data

Tags: php, mysql

I have a weird issue when dealing with a BLOG field coming from an iOS NSData source. I pass it through to a PHP web service.

The original source has a length of 10159. The PHP source has a length of 10159 when it gets to the web service. I enabled General Logging in MYSQL and verified that the prepared statement is actually getting original bytes that were sent from the client.

Here is the PHP code:

```
//call the stored procedure
$stmt2 = $this->db->prepare("CALL sp_event_master_create(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?, @event_master_id)");
$stmt2->bind_param('sssssssbsssi',   
    $event_name,
    $event_location,
    $mysql_start_date,
    $mysql_end_date,
    $event_website,
    $event_facebook,
    $event_description,
    $event_image,
    $event_contact_name,
    $event_contact_number,
    $event_contact_email,
    $event_app_user_id);

//set the image to be uploaded
$stmt2->send_long_data(7, $event_image);
```

When I query the BLOB field on the `getById` web service call, the size returned back to the client has ballooned to 22,325. The first bytes of the return look nothing like the original bytes sent to the database.

I tried to use `base64_decode` the blob returned but that didn't work. I know that I must have a setting incorrectly setup for the field or the database.

**PHP VERSION**: 5.5.3

**MYSQL VERSION**: 5.5.34

Comment: Here is the actual iOS->PHP size and first few bytes: Size 10159
89504e47 0d0a1a0a 0000000d 49484452 000000c8 00000032 08020000 00963303 b6000000 1c69444f 54000000 02000000 00000000 Here is the actual PHP->iOS size and first few bytes: Size of Image 23013
62706c69 73743030 d4010203 0405080b 0c542474 6f705824 6f626a65 63747358 24766572 73696f6e 59246172 63686976 6572d106   I added base64_encode and base64_decode on the web service but that didn't fix help.  The size in the database grew quite a bit though.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to actually be in RESKIT not in PHP or MYSQL.  I converted the field to a MEDIUMTEXT and the data that is in the database is correct.  I can see on the web service calls that the JSON data matches what was sent.

I have posted on the google group for reskit:  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/restkit/zMh98jCdGF0